# What's the color code of the green used in the the text selection toolbar / selection marker in gmail?

Tags: android, color-scheme

Under Honeycomb the text selection menu and the selection color in the gmail mail application as well as he start and end marker for a text copy are a light yellowish green. What's the exact color code for that color?  (I lack the tools to figure this out, ie. through a screen snapshot).   Is this a default color, can it be pooled from the system somehow ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install ColorZilla plugin to Mozilla firefox browser and open your screen shot in browser. You can get the RGB values on moving Colorzilla pointer on screen shot.

Comment: The method works well, the color is not uniform though, the bar along the title seems to be a gradient and the on page marker seem partitally transparent.  I finally settled on #98D70D.